# UIHint EditorTemplate is not working in asp.net core mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to use EditorTemplate in the asp.net core MVC project but it is not working.

Model Class exmaple:

```
[UIHint("YesNo")]
public int Status { get; set; }
```

My EditorTemplates folder in the shared folder. There is YesNo.cshtml.

If possible please share step by step.

Comment: how do you use `EditorFor`?

Comment: @KingKing it is not working.

Comment: *it's not working* is a very abstract description. I mean how did you write code to use your editor template? and `EditorFor` is one of the ways.

Comment: Hi @NoorAllSafaet,any update?If my answer help you resolve your issue,please remember to accept as answer?If not,could you please follow up to let me know?Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could follow the steps below:

1. Create the model:

   ```
   public class MyViewModel
   {
       [UIHint("YesNo")]
       public int Status { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Create Main view(Index.cshtml):

   ```
   @model MyViewModel

   <table>
       @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Status)
   </table>
   ```
3. Create Controller:

   ```
   [HttpGet]
   public IActionResult Index()
   {
       var oVm = new MyViewModel
       {
           Status=5
       };
       return View(oVm);
   }
   ```
4. Create `EditorTemplates` folder in `Views/Shared` folder.
5. Create `YesNo.cshtml` in `EditorTemplates`:

   [image]

**Note**:Remember that your `UIHint` attribute declared property type is integer,so
the partial view(`YesNo.cshtml`) allows the type of integer:

```
    @model int    //must be int
    <h2>Display YesNo.cshtml</h2>
    @Html.Label("Status", Model.ToString())
    @Html.Editor("Status")
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: @Rana I need to display yes or no instead of an int value. Your solution is showing int value.

Comment: @NoorAllSafaet the purpose of using `UIHint` is to suggest the framework with which template it uses to render the property using `EditorFor`. If the desired template is picked and executed, it's working (but you said it was not working). That's why it's very vague from the others' point of view. Here your problem is not that, it's just your `YesNo.cshtml` does not render an output you want. Your template has data (`Status`) passed in to render the result. That's all it need. If you want to show *Yes* or *No*, just convert the model `Status` to that kind of value accordingly.

Comment: Hi @NoorAllSafaet,As @King King said,If you want to display string value,the `Status `must be type of string.And in my answer I have said that the model type of partial view must be the same with the property type which declared with `UIHint`(Please see the Note in my answer carefully).

Comment: Though,you could display hard-coded Yes or No.Just add html like:`<h1>Yes</h1>` in your YesNo.cshtml.But it seems you do not want this,right?